# How can I make an html table column have the same width as its content?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html template into a pdf, however I ran into a problem. I currently use

> grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;

to set the first column to have the same width as its content. Unfortunately wkhtml can't use css grids, so I need another solution.

How can I set my first column to have the same width as its content?